# How to find an element within another element without an id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the values of some input element when a value of select dropdown changes.

When the select dropdown changes, i want to change some hidden textbox and a normal textbox which are with a td with `class="owner"`.

Within the `td` tag there are multiple elements with `type="hidden"` and one input type= text. I want to change the values of element with `type="hidden"` and `id` ending with `_lkid` and `_lkold` and then the only element within the `td` which is of `type="text"` and is within a `span` tag

I don't have an `id` of the elements within the `td` as they are generated automatically nor can i assign a class to those elements. i can only assign class to the `td`.

I am able to change the values of hidden text, but i am unsure of how to change the `type="text"` field. Any pointers would be helpful.

Jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/4honph7n/3/

This js is probably not the best/effective code written, taking some baby steps with jquery

HTML

```
<select class="selectClass">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="owner">
            <select>
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
            </select>
            <input type="hidden" id = "someid_lkid" value="00590000002BIF7">
            <input type="hidden" id = "someid_lkold" value="Some Text">
                <!-- there are some more hidden fields -->
         <span class="lookupInput">
            <input type="text" id = "someid" value="Some Text">
         </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.selectClass').change(function() {
        $('.owner').each(function(i) {
            $(this).find("input[type='hidden']").each(function(){
               if($(this).attr('id').indexOf("lkid") > -1){
                   $(this).val('new id');
                   alert($(this).val());
               }
               if($(this).attr('id').indexOf("lkold") > -1){
                   $(this).val('new text');
                   alert($(this).val());
               }


            })
        })

    })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to assign the same text/value to all inputs then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.selectClass').change(function () {
        $('.owner input[id$="lkid"]').val('new id');
        $('.owner input[id$="lkold"]').val('new text');

        $('.owner input:text').val('new val');

    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4honph7n/3/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.find()` with class selector along with child selector and [Attribute Ends with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

```
var textInput = $(this).find('.lookupInput input');
alert(textInput.val());

//Similarly you can use
var lkid = $(this).find("input[id$='_lkid']");
var lkold = $(this).find("input[id$='_lkold']");
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Lee6d6zk/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [attribute ends with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/):

```
var $lkid = $(this).find("input[id$='_lkid']"),
    $lkold = $(this).find("input[id$='_lkold']"),
    $text = $(this).find("input:text");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following selectors.

select hidden input with id containing 'lkid':
`$('[id*=lkid]')`

select hidden input with id containing 'lkold':
`$('[id*=lkold]')`

select text input:
`$('td.owner>span.lookupInput input[type=text]')`

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4honph7n/5/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.selectClass').change(function() {
        $(".owner input[id$='_lkid']").val('new id');
        $(".owner input[id$='_lkold']").val('new text');
        $(".owner span input[type=text]").val('new value');
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use some selectors for that like,

1. To get all inputs -> $("input")
2. To get all inputs with type attribute -> $("input[type]")
3. To get all hidden inputs -> $("input[type=hidden]")
4. To get all inputs with type ends with 'den' -> $("input[type$=den]")
5. To get all inputs with type starts with 'hid' -> $("input[type^=hid]")
6. To get all inputs with type contains 'idd' -> $("input[type*=idd]")

You can get more such selectors from here -> http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

Basically, jQuery selectors are CSS selectors...